# Metrics for Spring codec buffer

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, metrics

For our applications we usually set `spring.codec.max-in-memory-size: -1`, which is unlimited. We don't really have enough data to set this to a reasonable value.

Is there a way to get metrics or other data that shows the current buffer usage for codecs? If we had something like that, we could set `max-in-memory-size` to a reasonable value.

If there is no way to get that information, how does people set this value? Trial and error? Other tricks or tips?

Comment: Hi Kristoffer, are you using the WebClient.Builder? As I'm sure you are probably aware the codecs buffer 256KB by default, and I believe without using WebClient.Builder you always use the default value anyway. As far as I know there is no way to measure the actual buffer usage. You could measure at some other point however, not sure how worth it this is as having it unlimited may not cause problems.

Comment: @GuyLawrence-Downs thank you for your answer :) 
I see your point, my concern is related to potential security issues if it is set to unlimited. There probably is not any, but I would feel more confident if I set it to a specific value :)
I do use WebClient.Builder, but the default of 256KB does cause our application to fail. So, we need to set our own value.

Comment: No worries,  I agree actually that there is a chance of security issues, in terms of your time I'd say it's probably quicker to do a quick trial and error :)